# How to do a partial border for a button in css?

Tags: html, css

I would like to build this button in css:

[image]

We advised me to use ::after, and I success to do one part of this button. But just one line and I can't use manybalises ::after on a same component. How can I do ?

This is my css:

```css
.special_button{
    position: relative;
    background-color: white;
    height: 60px;
    font-size: 32px;
    width: 192px;
    font-family: dosis_light;
}

.special_button::after{
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    width: 33px;
    height: 2px;
    background: black;
    margin-top: 48px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

And my result:
[image]

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `:before` as well but instead of creating a single line, create the corner with each element.

```css
.special_button{
    position: relative;
    background-color: white;
    height: 60px;
    line-height:60px;
    font-size: 32px;
    font-family: dosis_light;
    border:none;
    padding:0 15px;
}

.special_button::before,
.special_button::after{
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    width: 33px;
    height: 20px;
}

.special_button::before{
    left:0;
    top:0;
    border-left:3px solid black;
    border-top:3px solid black;
}
.special_button::after{
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    border-right:3px solid black;
    border-bottom:3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<button class="special_button">ME CONTACTER</button>
```